# How to remove line based on Delimeter in perl / Shell?

Tags: shell, sed, awk, perl

Can anyone help to remove the line in file based on delimeter(Comma), Incase if line contain less number of columns or Bad records , Need to delete those.

```
Input File:

a,b,c,d
a,b,d,f
c,d
a,v,b,h
d,e,v,n
```

In the above file if the delimeter is less than 4 than i have to delete the line from the file.

```
Output File :

a,b,c,d
a,b,d,f
a,v,b,h
d,e,v,n
```

The below command gives me number of delimeter in a line , How can i delete if that not equal to 4,

```
egrep -iv '"' file.csv | awk -F',' '{print NF}'
```

Thanks.

Comment: No Empty records are fine , Which one in the below are faster in case huge files , Also is there a way we can edit inline instead of redirecting to new file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -F, -i.bak -ane 'print if @F > 3' file
```

With `perl` > 5.20, you can use `-F` without `-a` and `-n` (`-F` implies `-a` and `-a` implies `-n`).

Or you can use `sed`:

```
$ sed -i.bak -e '/\([^,]*,\)\{3,\}/!d' file
```

Comment: the `-i` option you used for sed is an non portable extension.

Comment: @llua: where is it non-portable? AFAIK, it matters only when `-i` without extension. In BSD and Mac, you need `-i ''`.

Comment: POSIX doesn't require the option, so OSs like openbsd, don't have it. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116

Comment: @llua: My bad, I don't know why I remember POSIX specify `-i`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Another perl: print a line if there are 3 commas.

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print if tr/,/,/==3' file
```

The `tr` operator returns the number of characters transliterated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F',' 'NF==4' file
```

If you can use `gawk` version >= 4.1.0 you can use `inplace`, more [info](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html).
So it could be:

```
gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak -F',' 'NF==4' file
```

Comment: Is there a way we can do it inline instead of redirecting ?

Comment: I added more to the answer.

Comment: @talizin We have gawk < 3.0 version

Comment: Then I think you can not do it with awk except creating temporary file or with a risk losing your data..., but the -i option in sed or perl is not magic, it also creates a temporary file, they just handle it for you.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -nE '/^.+,.+,.+,.+$/p' file > output_file
```